# Server reached MaxClients occurring continuously after MySQL upgrade

Tags: mysql, apache, client, upgrade

Everything was running fine, and then after a MySQL upgrade from 5.0 to 5.1 and then 5.5, which was somewhat faulty (some table prefixes were messed up and a little bit of data was lost but nothing major), we have had this new issue arise out of the blue.

As far as I can tell, no config settings were changed for Apache (httpd.conf), MySQL (my.cnf), or PHP (php.ini).

I checked the Apache logs from before the upgrade, and we were not hitting MaxClients at all.

Now we hit it all the time (9 times in one day!), and when we do all webpages on the server become completely inaccessible, requiring an Apache restart - and they never seem to become accessible again until I complete the restart, although granted I don't really want to wait around and find out if it ever will come out of it.

Previously our MaxClients and ServerLimit were set to 1000 - I upped it to 3000 and although the frequency of reaching MaxClients has seemed to decline, it is still occurring. We have 96.0 GB of RAM and usage never goes beyond 30 GB, usually much lower.

I checked the logs from before and after and bot crawling activity seems to be approximately the same.

I'm wondering if some other settings could have been changed that would have resulted in this occurring? Or if anyone has any other ideas I would very much appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

We had a case of "PBS": http://techmythsworld.blogspot.com/2011/11/solving-httpd-maxclients-and-modstatus.html

W's were accumulating until we kept hitting MaxClients. The problem may have existed all along to some extent, but then been exacerbated by some sort of change in config settings during and/or near the time of the upgrade, I am not sure. However, I am sure that we fixed it by changing our code a little bit so that processes would die after a set period of time vs. waiting for a certain number of loops to occur. That being said, may be a good idea to have some sort of script in place to kill off stale processes that slip through the cracks, and then log them.

In case the above mentioned link goes down, you will want to check your processes via command line utilizing:

> > service httpd fullstatus > outputfile.txt

If you see an accumulation of W's, scroll down and if you find a pattern of one or two scripts accounting for most of them, that(those) will likely be your culprit(s). To ensure the accumulation is legitimate, you may want to check once, then check back an hour later and see if it has continued. You will notice the W's have continuously increasing SS's (seconds since beginning of most recent request).